# Backup Nexus Login, LDAP config and artifacts uploaded

Tags: docker, docker-volume, sonatype, nexus3

I have fired up a nexus3 in ec2 instance (dockerized) with changes:

- LDAP Mapping config, roles and realms
- S3 Blobstore mapping
- Custom repository mapping
- Admin username and password

I have an ebs for its volume. But after we terminated and start up a new instance with dockerized Nexus3.

We created a docker volume and we mount it in /nexus-data as indicated in this link:
https://hub.docker.com/r/sonatype/nexus3/

However, when we fired up a new ec2 instance and a new docker image and mounting the old docker volume, all the changes were gone.

- LDAP Mapping config, roles and realms
- S3 Blobstore mapping
- Custom repository mapping
- Admin username and password

Is there a missing step or are we doing it incorrectly?
Please advise.

Comment: You need to put the work directory on persistent storage:  https://github.com/sonatype/docker-nexus3#persistent-data

Comment: Hi @rseddon thank you so much. I found that issue that the ebs_volume is not attached correctly to my ec2 instance where the nexus docker is running. Thnaks